# My program complies but doesn't print anything

Tags: java

I am writing this program that checks if `{` `[` `(` `"` `/*` are balanced with `}` `]` `)` `"` `*/` We are required to ignore stuff in the comment blocks. I ran into an issue when I run my code in terminal nothing gets printed out. I know where the error is but I don't know why it is wrong. I start getting this weird issue after I attempt to write code for ignoring comments. We need to write out own stack class called MyStack.java but it is pretty straightforward so I will not include here.

I think problem happens here:

```
int start = str.indexOf("/*");
int end = str.indexOf("*/");
if(start != -1){
  str = str.substring(0,start) + str.substring(end+2);
```

Here is the entire code: I hope there isn't any logical fallacy

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SymbolBalance {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(args.length>0){
            try{
                Scanner input = new Scanner(new File (args[0]));
                MyStack<Character> ms = new MyStack<>();
                String str;
                char ch;
                boolean quoteStart = true;
                loop: while(input.hasNext()){
                    str = input.next();
                    int start = str.indexOf("/*");
                    int end = str.indexOf("/*");
                    if(start != -1){
                      str = str.substring(0,start) + str.substring(end+2);
                        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
                        ch = str.charAt(i);      
                            if(ch == '{'||ch =='(' || ch=='[')     
                                {
                               ms.push(ch);
                                }
                            else if((ch == '/'&&i<str.length() -1&&str.charAt(i+1)=='*')){
                                ms.push(str.charAt(i+1));
                            }

                            else if (ch==')'){
                                if(ms.isEmpty()||ms.pop()!= '('){
                                   System.out.println(") is mismatched");
                                   break loop;
                                }
                            }
                           else if(ch == ']'){
                                if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '['){
                                    System.out.println("] is mismatched");
                                    break loop;
                                }      
                           }
                            else if(ch == '}'){
                                if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '{'){
                                    System.out.println("} is mismatched");
                                    break loop;
                                }
                            }
                            else if(ch == '*' && i<str.length()-1&&str.charAt(i+1) == '/'){
                                if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '*'){
                                    System.out.println("*/ is mismatched");
                                    break loop;
                                }   
                            }
                           else if(ch == '"'){
                                if(quoteStart == true) {
                                    ms.push(ch);
                                    quoteStart = false;
                               }
                                else {
                                    if(ms.isEmpty() || ms.pop() != '"'){
                                        System.out.println(" \" is mismatched");  
                                        break loop;
                                    }
                                    quoteStart = true;
                                }
                            }  
                       }
                    }
                }
                input.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                   System.out.println("Cannot find file");
            }

        }
        else{
               System.out.println("No command line argument");
        }
    }

}
```

Here I include an example input file:

```
/* this is to test whether the program ignores imbalances in the comment blocks */
public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean haveYouWatchedHamiltonYet = true;
        int theSchuylerSisters = 3; 
        int alexanderhamilton = 1;
        int aaronburr = 1;

        boolean amIintheroom = theRoomWhereItHappens();


        /* this is a commented block. We're testing if your code 
        can deal with unbalanced things in the comments: /*
        that was the test for here */
    }

    /*just a general comment */ 
    /* this one has some  errors /* { [  { [ } ] */   


    public boolean theRoomWhereItHappens() {
        boolean intheRoomWhereItHappens = false;
        boolean isHappyAboutThis = false;
        return intheRoomWhereItHappens && isHappyAboutThis;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should debug your code before asking a question.

Comment: "*I think problem happens here*" why do you think that? What do you suspect the problem *is*? What have you tried? What issues have you run into, that you're not sure how to address? StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a debugging service.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: please post the input file

Comment: just included an example

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same characters for both the start and end of comments:

```
    int start = str.indexOf("/*");
    int end = str.indexOf("/*");
```

The end comment string should be:

```
    int end = str.indexOf("*/");
```

Comment: hi, even after this edit the code still doesnt work.